# Using custom-aligned subarray in LyX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, fontsize, subscripts

I need to write a vertically stacked subscript in a notation meant to say "evaluate expression at k=..., and k'=...". In the end it should look like

```
/    SOME    \        
|     BIG    |        
\ EXPRESSION / k = ...
               k'= ...
```

with the "k=, k'=" part as subscript in normal subscript size (hence the `matrix` environnment is unsuitable). In LaTeX I'd use the `subarray` environment and indeed **LyX** supports a command `\subarray`. However, I can't find a method to change the alignment from centered to left-aligned.

When inserting a matrix similarly just writing `\matrix` in the equation editor gives a matrix where all columns are centered and I know no method to change this after creation, while using the "Insert > Math > Matrix" dialog allows specifying the alignment. A method for changing matrix alignment would probably also allow aligning `subarray`.

Does such a method exist or is there a dialog based method to create a `subarray`environment similar to matrix?

#### Clarification

I want the result to look correct in **LyX's** math editor, in the output document and in the LyX's instant preview. The closest I got was defining a **LyX** math macro with two arguments that inserts a left-aligned matrix (which in the math editor looks like a `\begin{subarray}{l}...\end{subarray}`) and then overwriting it with ERT to actually use `subarray` for the pdf output. However, for instant preview this will use `\begin{matrix}{l}...\end{matrix}` and thus look incorrect.

Comment: `\begin{subarray}[l] k=...\\ k'=...\end{subarray}`

Comment: I also don't use/know Lyx.  I have a solution using my `stackengine` package, but won't post it if it is useless in a Lyx context.

Comment: The `mathtools` package has starred versions of `matrix, bmatrix, pmatrix`, &c., environments, that accept an optional argument (`[l], [r]` or \ [c]` – the default).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a feature-request for adjusting displays of internal content that forms part of the LyX UI. See http://www.lyx.org/GetInvolved.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is using `\begin{subarray}{l}...\end{subarray}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left[\frac{k}{k'}\right]_{\begin{subarray}{l} k=1\\k'=2+4\end{subarray}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly I can't find a way to do that properly in LyX (which the question is about). While I can create such an effect by using mixing LyX's builtin Mathmacros and overwriting my macro with ERT (i.e. plain latex), I don't know how to consistently get this result in LyX's math editor, in instant preview for the expression and in the output document.

Comment: @kdb Sorry for that, but I'm not a LyX user and can't help you more than this. If LyX puts so many constraints, leave it or ask the developers to make available the well documented `subarray` environment.